# Pinch to zoom and pan to move

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp

I have figured out, that I can use `ScrollViewer` in iOS and in `Android` I can use [this ScaleImageView from XamarinAndroidToolkit](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MonoDroidToolkit/blob/master/src/XamarinAndroidToolkit/Toolkit/ScaleImageView.cs).

But what can I use for UWP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use `ScrollViewer` for this purpose as well. You will however need to enable zooming and both scroll bars for the control. Vertical scroll bar should be set to `Auto` by default, but horizontal is by default disabled. The same goes for the zoom mode.
If you want to hide the scroll bars, you can do so after explicitly enabling the scrolling.

```
<ScrollViewer ZoomMode="Enabled" 
              HorizontalScrollMode="Auto"                
              VerticalScrollMode="Auto"  
              VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" 
              HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
              >
   ...
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: You will have to enable both scroll bars. I have updated the answer to reflect that

Comment: But I do not want the scrollbars to appear

Comment: Yes, that is also possible - I have updated the answer appropriately.